# Python Generator that yields more results takes more time to create

Tags: python, generator

I have the following code in Python:

```
import time
import sys

def returnlist(times):
    t = time.time()
    l = [i for i in range(times)]
    print "list: {}".format(time.time() - t)
return l

def returngenerator(times):
    t = time.time()
    g = (i for i in range(times))
    print "generator: {}".format(time.time() - t)
    return g

g = returngenerator(times)
l = returnlist(times)
```

1.For times = 1000000 I get the results:

> generator: 0.107323884964
>
> list: 0.225493192673

2.For times = 10000000 I get:

> generator: 0.856524944305
>
> list: 1.83883309364

I understand why the 2nd list would take more time to create but why would the 2nd generator take more time as well? I assumed that due to lazy evaluation it would take about the same time to create as the 1st generator.

I am running this program on an Ubuntu VM

Comment: Are you running Python 2? If that's the case, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: @Carsten is completely right, the reasons that this is slower in python-2 is that `range` only became lazy (i.e. returns a generator) with python-3 while before it evaluated the full list.

Comment: So I take it that I should never use range() in bulding generators.
Would using range() mean that every time a new generator value is to be returned the whole range() list should be created again?

Comment: Also you would be better off if you use 'timeit' module for timing analysis. Say something like: import timeit;  t1=timeit.Timer(setup='x=100000',stmt='(y for y in xrange(x))');t1.timeit(1000)

Comment: @GeorgeG Yes, if you care for lazyness and/or memory efficiency you should always use `xrange` in generators.

Comment: @Carsten You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @HerrActress Done. I've had some problems because the two benchmark functions ate all my memory. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function. In Python 2, it creates a list. For large lists like the ones in your benchmarks, this becomes a problem. In Python 3, `range` returns a generator. A workaround for Python 2 is to use the [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) function, which is lazy as well.

As a test, let's create a benchmark function like yours, but using xrange:

```
def returngenerator2(times):
    t = time.time()
    g = (i for i in xrange(times))
    print "generator2: {}".format(time.time() - t)
    return g
```

And test it:

```
>>> l = returnlist(10**7)
list: 0.580000162125
>>> g = returngenerator(10**7)
generator: 0.115000009537
>>> x = returngenerator2(10**7)
generator2: 0.0
>>> x2 = returngenerator2(10**8)
generator2: 0.0
>>> x3 = returngenerator2(10**9)
generator2: 0.0
```

Seems to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `range()` returns an actual list in Python 2. In python 3, this was changed so that `range()` was a generator. Use `xrange()` in Python 2 to improve performance.